# How to Exit primaryStage while opening a new stage in javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx, exit, stage

I am trying to figure out how to exit the primaryStage in javafx while opening another stage
upon clicking a button, what is the code to remove the primary stage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
primaryStage.close();
```

or

```
primaryStage.hide();
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close--), these are completely equivalent. It could be argued that since `hide()` is defined in the superclass, it is more general and therefore slightly preferred. For example, if you don't have a reference to the `primaryStage` directly, but to some node that is displayed in it, you can do

```
someNode.getScene().getWindow().hide();
```

but using `close()` this way requires a cast.

One "gotcha": by default, when the last window displayed is closed, the application will exit. So if you do

```
primaryStage.close();
Stage newStage = new Stage();
Scene newScene = new Scene(...);
newStage.setScene(newScene);
newStage.show();
```

bad things could happen, because you could implicitly exit the application before the new stage is shown(!). You can change the default behavior here with

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

or, of course re-order the code so that the new stage is opened before the existing one is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The code to remove a stage is :

```
stage.close();
```

with variable stage corresponding to the stage you want to exit

Comment: Simply use stage.close or what you can do is just change the scene on top of the same stage .

Comment: Use stage.close();

Answer (score 0):

set fx:id on your button

```
<JFXButton fx:id="btn_login" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="242.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0098DA;" text="Login" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
```

in your java controller

```
Stage stage = (Stage) btn_login.getScene().getWindow();
```

Actionevent

```
private void act_login(ActionEvent event) { //login pressed
    stage.close();
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxmlFile/main.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    primaryStage.setTitle("Main Aplikasi Keuangan");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```